# Filtering Rollups In Notion Database Queries

Tags: notion-api

Does anyone have the format for a filter on a Notion rollup property? I can’t get the structure right. I’m filtering a Show Original rollup of a Select property here and this isn’t working -

```
{
    "filter": {
        "property": "Status",
        "rollup": {
            {
                "any": {
                    "select": {
                        "name": {
                            "contains": "Active"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct format was -

```
{
    "filter": {
        "property": "Status",
        "rollup": {
            "any": {
                "select": {
                    "equals": "Active"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```